# nHibernate generated this odd bit of SQL; did SQLS consume it as is?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, azure-sql-database

As a result of the following LINQ:

```
plans
  .Where(p => p.Attributes.Any(a => a.Attribute.Product.Type == callType) && 
    call.StartTime < p.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value) &&
    call.StartTime > p.StartDate.GetValueOrDefault(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value))
```

Plans are something like mobile phone plans. Let's say there's a base price of $1 per minute for international calls, and that contract has null start and end times because it's the base. A special plan for december is created, starting on teh 1st and ending on the last day of the month. This plan should override the base (and it will later, with a `.OrderBy` endtime-starttime [i.e. the shorter a plan the more overriding it is] + `.First`, but that's not interesting to me right now) but it should only apply to calls made in Dec, hence the two clauses that ensure we only look for plans that support the call type, and have a start/end date that straddles the time the call was made

This translates to the following SQL according to the output window debug from nHibernate:

```
and 
  (exists 
    (
      ..blah blah blah.. 
      where product7_.Type=?
    )
  ) and ?<coalesce(plan4_.EndDate, ?) and ?>coalesce(plan4_.StartDate, ?)
```

I get the EXISTS (blahblahblah) as that's derived from the `p.Any()`, but what's the funky SQL in the angle brackets?

it looks like `) and ?<coalesce(plan4_.EndDate, ?) and ?>coalesce(plan4_.StartDate, ?)` should be (in regular SQL syntax)

```
and call.starttime BETWEEN COALESCE(plan.StartDate, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(plan.EndDate, '9999-12-31')
```

Does SQLServer do something with it as output by nHibernate, or is some other part of nHibernate responsible for expanding this to something more like my "regular" SQL? (nhibernate runs in sqlserver2008 mode, but the target is azure)

Comment: `myNullableDate.GetValueOrDefault(someDateValue)` on a nullable date, returns `myNullableDate.Value` if `myNullableDate.HasValue`, or the provided `someDateValue` value if the nullable is null. COALESCE returns the first non null argument encountered, reading from left to right

Comment: I don't necessarily trace the actual SQL that arrives at the database; I trace the sql prepared by nHibernate using an Interceptor
 `public class SqlStatementInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
    {
        public override global::NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(global::NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(sql.ToString());
            return sql;
        }
    }`

Comment: Are you able to run a trace and see what is submitted to the database?

Comment: I'm not certain; this project is already a massive amount of unfamiliar ground, as I was not on the original dev team, and none of our other stuff uses nH/castlewindsor.. Perhaps it's simpler to assume that nH does some more manipualting of the SQL string after it finished `Prepare`ing it, because I'm near 100% certain SQLServer won't do anything with that, even though it sort-of looks like a parameterised query (odbc style, mind, not sqlserver @param style). Perhaps breaking in the interceptor and stepping-in will allow me  to see where else it goes

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/ may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is there's no funky SQL in angle-brackets :)

Look closer, those are the `<` (lesser-than) and `>` (greater-than) operators in your query which are also supported in SQL.
The lack of spaces is confusing you.

The `?` symbol is a common placeholder for the positional parameters in your query as those are not sent inline with the SQL text (in this case, the value of `call.StartTime` and the max/min date values).

You can interpret it as:

```
and :startTime < coalesce(plan4_.EndDate, :sqlTimeMaxValue) and :startTime > coalesce(plan4_.StartDate, :sqlTimeMinValue)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Fredy; I think it needed a second pair of eyes looking at it to see that interpretation - couldn't see the sql for the code!